# Как отследить изменения класса у элемента с jquery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть элементы разметки, например теги li, которые находится в ротации и им поочередно присваивается и убирается класс "active". Как можно отслеживать изменения класса и если класс изменился, например с "active" на "current" вызывать другую функцию? Влезть в скрипт ротатора нет возможности.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если css классы присваиваются при помощи функции jquery addClass, то достаточно просто ее перезаписать, и таким способом перехватывать вызов:

```
var origFn = $.fn.addClass;  
$.fn.addClass = function(className)
{
    //  Выполняем здесь необходимый нам код
    //  и вызываем оригинальную функцию

    origFn.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: только вот не `$.fn.val` а все-таки наверно `$.fn.addClass`

Comment: извиняюсь) скопировал просто кусок своего кода, и не везде на addClass поменял

Answer (score 2):

Оперируй в логических выражениях чем-то на подобие этого:

```
$("li").hasClass("current")
```

Дальше - дело техники...

Answer (score 1):

Если их не очень много, при загрузке страницы запустить функцию, которая соберет в массив значения классов у этих элементов.

Затем раз в секунду (например) снова пробегаться циклом по элементам и сравнить с массивом, запустить все, что надо, новые значения - в массив. И по кругу.

Comment: ничего себе, это на крайний случай