# Событие на измение содержимого блока

Tags: jquery

Есть возможность отловить изменение содержимого блока?

Comment: нет такого события в DOM, но в дебагере - можно.

Comment: прошу уточнить для чего это необходимо, т.к. вопрос слишком широкий. И общего решения я не знаю.., но возможно для ваших целей есть решение :)

Comment: Есть 4 блока .galereya-slider-slide, у активного всегда есть класс .current. Мне нужно поймать момент когда .current переходит от одного блока к другому.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(selector).bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/nWbuh/

Либо же сделать какой-нибудь таймер, который будет пробегаться и проверять изменения.

Comment: в консоль ничего не попадает, браузер chrome

Comment: `DOMSubtreeModified` относиться к так называемым [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events) и считается устаревшим. Вместо него можно использовать [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), но возникает также вопрос о поддержке в разных браузерах.

Answer (score 1):

Если `.current` устанавливается на элемент при помощи функции jQuery `addClass`, то достаточно ее переписать чтобы отслеживать изменения.

Похожий вопрос здесь уже был: [Как отследить изменения класса у элемента с jquery?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/19240/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-jquery)

Есть еще [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) для отслеживания изменений, но поддерживается не всеми браузерами.