# Событие удаления элемента из dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Есть ли в JavaScript/jQuery событие, реагирующее на удаление элемента из dom? Не нашел такого. Нужна реакция на любое удаление - не только функцией `remove` (jQuery), но и, например, удаление `p` внутри `contenteditable`.

К чему все это? Надо отменять удаление элемента - блокировать удаление некоторых областей при `contenteditable="true"`.

Comment: http://javascript.ru/forum/events/21796-sobytie-na-izmenenie-soderzhaniya.html#post127917

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/245065/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: я бы хотел добавить ссылку https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events#Performance где указана потеря в скорости в 1.5 - 7 раз.

Comment: @splash58 оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ